# In our community ads, what is "Oskeron"

Tags: discussion

This ad appears on other SE sites' sidebar:

[image]

I have looked around but found nothing to indicate what the significance of Oskeron is, either here on WB.SE or the internet in general.  I thought it might be a literary or cinematic reference, but nothing comes up.

Comment: I think not knowing about it is the point. Maybe. I guess you fell for it?

Comment: I honestly have no idea...thats strange

Comment: Don't know why, but when I hear "Oskeron" I can't help but think it's a bastardization of "Ask Around."

Comment: Heh. Only just seen this. You can blame me, I created the ad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was commented about at the time, the person who created the advert used it as the name of a fictional world and just invented it for the ad. It was suggested that it might be confusing but unless someone wants to create another ad (or modify that one) it's what we get.

On the bright side it did cause some curiosity and discussion :)

Comment: And when are our graphics and full-site status going to kick in, anyway?